# is it ok to combine one machine with network driver ixgbe and other machine with network driver i40e

Tags: networking, redhat, linux-networking, kernel, drivers

we have two rhel server redhat 7.6 and redhat 7.2

on the first server 7.2 , the network driver is `driver: ixgbe`

on the second server rhel 7.6 the network driver is `driver: i40e`

dose redhat Linux machines with different driver can cause network problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network drivers need to be compatible with network interface cards (NICs), so that the hardware can function properly. Machines can talk to each other regardless of network driver type as far as they use standard protocols like TCP/IP stack.